# Puzzles/Puzzle Clues Related to Narrow/Restrictive Topics like Video Games

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I see some puzzles that I believe are only relatable to people who might have been exposed to certain (albeit) popular video games or other media. Should these be allowed given that the clue or puzzle is otherwise unsolveable, or worse, unknowingly unsolveable by someone who's not familiar with it? Or maybe a tag that indicates that the clues will not lead a reasonable person to be able to ascertain the game or device/product, etc.?

This question has been asked, but is slightly different:
[Are questions about puzzle video games on topic?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1590/are-questions-about-puzzle-video-games-on-topic)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think we need to go banning anything, but I do see the "unknowingly unsolvable" issue as a challenge. However, I think the solution is as simple as making better use of the tags we already have. There are tags for many common "niche" subject areas, such as [video-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games), [movies](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies), [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language), [geography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography), etc. And failing that, [trivia](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) is a pretty good catch-all, for any puzzle that requires "[nonessential, specifically detailed knowledge on topics of popular culture](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/trivia/info)".

The issue is simply that often people don't always apply the appropriate tags. This is possibly due to the misconception that a puzzle, or its solution, needs to be *about* something in order for it to be tagged as such.

For example, a good riddle would not usually require specialised knowledge and its solution would be an everyday object/concept, so tagging  [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle) would be sufficient. However, if the solution, the presentation, or *any* of the clues, required more niche knowledge, it should probably have additional tags to indicate as much.

Appropriate tagging should not only categorise and curate, but it should also set the expectations of the solvers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that tags, as mentioned by [Alconja](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja), help us to classify the puzzles and choose whether to go for the problem or not.

Yes, obviously,

> some puzzles are only relatable to people who might have been exposed to certain (albeit) popular video games or other media.

For example take this: [Pokemon is very specific tag for Puzzling](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30998680#30998680), and [it has only 3 questions here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon). Actually, it has caused [a chaos on gaming.SE](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11804/pok%C3%A9mon-gotta-qatch-em-all)

> Should these be allowed given that the clue or puzzle is otherwise unsolvable, or worse, unknowingly unsolvable by someone who's not familiar with it? Or maybe a tag that indicates that the clues will not lead a reasonable person to be able to ascertain the game or device/product, etc.?

Why not? It would be fun for the enthusiasts of that particular, say game or the TV show.